# Add external plugin using django-ckeditor

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'm trying to install [this details](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/detail) plugin for CKEditor 4, using [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor). I can't find a syntax that makes the button appear for me.

I've put the plugin folder at `/static/js/lib/ckeditor-plugins/detail/`. It contains a `plugin.js`. I can view that file in the browser at that URL.

In my Django `settings.py` I have this (minimal example):

```py
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    "default": {
        "addExternal": ",".join(
            [
                "detail",
                "/static/js/lib/ckeditor-plugins/detail/",
                "plugin.js",
            ]
        ),
        "toolbar": [
            {
                "name": "paragraph",
                "groups": ["blocks"],
                "items": [
                    "Blockquote",
                    "Detail",
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But there's no extra Detail button next to the Blockquote one. The Network tab of web dev tools doesn't show the plugin's `plugin.js` being loaded.

I've tried changing the `"addExternal"` to this:

```py
        "addExternal": [
            ("detail", "/static/js/lib/ckeditor-plugins/detail/", "plugin.js"),
        ],
```

But it's no different. I feel I'm missing one crucial step or change.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [config](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor?tab=readme-ov-file#example-ckeditor-configuration) you've to add plugins in `extraPlugins` instead of `addExternal`

```py
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    "default": {
        "toolbar": [
            {
                "name": "paragraph",
                "groups": ["blocks"],
                "items": [
                    "Blockquote",
                    "Detail",
                ],
            }
        ],
        "extraPlugins": ",".join(
            [
                "detail",
            ]
        ),
    }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure you've downloaded plugin and added inside your plugin folder.